# How to get rid of text at the start of a string?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I have a text file, and it starts off with some text before getting to the data that I need for my program. How do I go about getting rid of this text and pick up only the data behind it?

The file reads like so:

`Text text text text text text text text 2010 1 0.00 0.00 0.00`

I'd like to totally skip the text and get straight to the data which starts with `2010`.

My current way of reading the text file and sorting it into an array is using `scanner()` like so:

```
public void readFile(){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while(rainFile.hasNext()){

        String a = rainFile.next();
        sortedData[i][j][k] = a;
        k++;
        if(k==31){
            j++;
            k=0;
            if(j==12){
                i++;
                j=0;
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

My array is being sorted just fine, but short of manually deleting the text at the start of the file I don't know how to exclude it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it literally "text" repeated, or is it that you know the first part you want starts with 4 digits, or what?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

```
a = a.substring(a.indexOf("2010"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [String#indexOf(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method to find the first occurence of 2010. For example:

```
String text = "Text text text text text text text text 2010 1 0.00 0.00 0.00";
String start = text.substring(text.indexOf("2010"));
System.out.println(start);
```

This piece of code will give output `2010 1 0.00 0.00 0.00`.